# Why is the address length argument is pointer in the function accept() and recv()?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, socklen-t

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

I don't understand why the `addrlen` argument is pointer, but not `socklen_t` ?

Comment: it's to be able to _write_ the length back. It's an input/output parameter: "The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must
       initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed
       to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer
       address."

Comment: As above. This is fairly common, needing to provide the size of the structure you're passing in, and the function passing the number of elements used back

Comment: Could you clarify your question: you say you don't understand why the `addrlen` is a pointer, but not `socklen_t`. The first part makes sense but I can't understand what you mean about `socklen_t`

Answer (score 1):

That's because It's an input/output parameter and you have no other choice in C-interfaced functions than to pass a pointer on the variable so it can be changed by the callee if needed.

From the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address."

As you see, even if you specify a size, the system returns the *actual* size (which may be different from the one you specified)

and also for this case:

> When addr is NULL,
>          nothing is filled in; in this case, addrlen is not used, and should
>          also be NULL.

Here, why passing a value if it's not used?